# Equivalent condition for finite cyclic commutative group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite, commutative group. Is

$$\text{$G$ is cyclic.}$$
equivalent to

$$\text{For each $n$, there are at most $n$ pairwise  different elements of $G$,}$$
$$\text{such that the order of such an element divides $n$.}$$
?

Comment: "$n$ pairwise different elements" is a long-winded way of saying "$n$ elements"... Anyway, yes. This should be proved in most intro texts that cover abelian groups, no?

Comment: I think both directions have already been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346936/finite-group-for-which-xxm-e-leq-m-for-all-m-is-cyclic and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517113/can-we-conclude-that-this-group-is-cyclic?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I guess that's just the backward direction. The forward direction is not hard.

Comment: Ok. This is simply again using $\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$ and $\phi(d)$ is the amount of elements with order $d$. (Since $G$ is cyclic there is only one subgroup of order $d$)